# How to read Gmail or Gapps mail message without IMAP/POP3

Tags: c#, gmail

Can somebody please suggest me a way to read gmail or gapps mailbox without using IMAP/POP3. Is there any third party library that can read mails by disabling IMAP/POP3?

Thanks,
Haseena

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google's [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-cs). This will give you access over a RESTful interface without having to enable POP or IMAP. However, you do have to activate API access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Are there any .net API for the same or REST is the only way for reading mail data?

Comment: The link in my answer refers to the .NET libraries to access the REST API.

Comment: I was struggling to find some sample code for reading mail using .net API over REST, currently found samples were based on java and php. could you please suggest?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list i could find the help here :)

Comment: Can i use Service account with Gmail API? i tried using it i was sucessfully able to create the gmail service object but on calling message List API it throws an exception. I am writing a desktop based application and would like to use OAuth.

Comment: Yes you can. The scopes have to be correctly set though, both on the service account, and in the client application. I no longer remember the exact details, so you'll have to Google a bit or post a new question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

There new Gmail RESTful API

there librarys for Java .Net and Python

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/

Comment: does that support OAuth?